# What is a portable way to save double values to a file?

Tags: c++, c++11, save, binaryfiles

I want to store data to a binary file using `mmap`. To make sure that my solution is portable I want to use types with specified width (`uint32_t` and friends) to save my data.

However, I also have to save a few `double` values. From looking at the `<cstdint>` header it seems there are no floating point types defined. Also `double` does not seem to have a fixed width and representation.

How can I save (and load) floating point values from my binary file in a portable way? Do I need to convert them to an integer type to save them?

Comment: The only portable way to store floating point numbers is text.

Comment: Print the number bits into a text file. For example, cast the float to an int and print that int in hex format

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: It's arguable as then you lose the exact binary representation and get a decimal approximation.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It may not be exact, but at least it's portable re endianness etc

Comment: @arne: seamless portability is over-rated, I much prefer a thoroughly documented format. Especially since textual formats are not exactly performance-friendly.

Comment: There are two types of _portable_ here. The program itself should be portable, but does the same also apply to the created file ? I think the latter is implied.

Comment: `uint32_t` is only portable to systems that have an unsigned type with **exactly** 32 bits. Granted, that's a lot of systems, but it's not all, and there is rarely a need for such a stringent constraint. `uint_least32_t` or `uint_fast32_t` would be much better.

Comment: @PeteBecker If I want to read 32 bits from a memory mapped binary file then it is my understanding that I need a type that is **exactly** 32 bits wide. Am I incorrect?

Comment: @Chris - you're right. Sorry, I overlooked the mention of `mmap`. I also tend to react strongly to those overused exact-sized types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want (or need) to achieve.

In short, you have two solutions:

- store as decimal, this implies a conversion but can be read however one wants
- store as binary, this implies a known bit-width and byte order

There is also a mix solution: a textual binary representation, `0xd775u7f1...`, for each of the number. The main advantage is that you have no byte order issue, but on the other hand you still suffer from the bit-width issue (though it can be deduced from the representation).

I would advise you to simply create a format and document it. A simple format would be:

- binary
- 64 bits
- Little-Endian

(which is what 64 bits programs running on x86 use)

This is portable *because* it is specified, although it may be faster on some platforms.

Answer (score 3):

I am expanding on the "mix solution" Matthieu M. alluded to in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18374771/341970).

I would convert the numbers into hexadecimal strings and back, using the `%a` and `%la` format specifiers from the ISO C99 Standard. <strike>As far as I know we don't have a similar facility in C++11, unfortunately.</strike>

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  double x = 0.1;

  char* str = "0X1.999999999999AP-4";

  printf("0.1 in hexadecimal is: %A\n", x);

  printf("Now reading %s\n", str);

  /* in a production code I would check for errors */
  sscanf(str, "%lA", &x); /* note: %lA is used! */

  printf("It equals %g\n", x);

}
```

Standard, portable, no hassle with the byte order, no loss of precision, but requires more storage space.

---

**UPDATE:** Although the compiler support is still catching up, there is a C++11 solution, see [`std::hexfloat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed).